# cannot install auto-complete package

Tags: auto-complete-mode

I am trying to install package [auto-complete](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete). But when I typed M-x package-install [ret], then emacs showed "contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:80". After a while, it showed "Install package". Then I typed "auto-complete", it prompted "no match". Do I miss something here? thanks.

Comment: Do you set MELPA or MELPA stable repository to package-archives ? If not yet, please set. See Also http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_package_system.html

Comment: company-mode is better.

Comment: Try `M-x list-packages'. See if you find auto-complete in there.

Comment: @Malabarba, I tried. it's not in there

Comment: @city How many entries are listed when you list-packages? Is it around dozens or thousands?

Comment: @Malabarba, thousands. and I figured out it's our company permission problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following has been tested to work on an `emacs -Q` session:

1. Launch `emacs -Q`
2. Add the below in the scratch buffer:

```el
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
```

3. Evaluate the buffer (`M-x eval-buffer`)
4. Do `M-x package-install RET auto-complete RET`

The package will install.

Note that step 4 will NOT work if you already have the package installed in the `~/.emacs.d/elpa/` folder. So to test this, either move the `elpa/` folder to something like `elpa.bkp/` before step 1 or do `M-x list-packages` (after step 3), find the `auto-complete` package in there, hit `d` to mark it for deletion and then `x` to execute the deletion. Then step 4 will work once again.

Comment: at step 3, I got "Symbol's value as variable is void: package-archives". and I deleted epla/ and restart emacs. It doesn't work. Maybe the reason is our company doesn't allow us connect the third party website directly. thanks anyway.

Comment: @city I added a `require` statement in step 2. Can you please try again? Also, what is your emacs version (M-x emacs-version) ?

Comment: I tried it again. it still didn't work. my emacs version GNU Emacs 24.3.1

Comment: I repeated those exact steps in an emacs -Q session on emacs 24.3 and they worked fine. What doesn't work? What errors/messages do you see in the messages buffer? You can quickly access that buffer using `C-h e`.

Comment: I just proved it's our company's permission problem. I set up a proxy. it works now. thanks.

Comment: But now I get this warning. Do you have any idea? thanks.
In end of data:
auto-complete-config.el:544:1:Warning: the following functions are not known to be defined:
    semantic-analyze-current-context, semantic-tag-class,
    semantic-tag-function-arguments, yas-expand-snippet,
    semantic-format-tag-type, semantic-format-tag-name

Comment: @city When do you get those warnings? If they happen while installing the package, you can ignore them. But you should not see warnings in the \*Messages\* buffer at emacs startup. If you do, start a new question with adequate detail related to that problem.

Comment: I tried to install both auto-complete and company. I am sure they are installed, but they don't work as expected. I suspect it's related to these compiling warnings.

Comment: @city I am curious to see the issue you are facing. Can you start a new question with all the details on what you see and how one can recreate that?

Comment: see my another question: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10688/compiling-waring-when-installing-auto-cpmplete-package-in-emacs-24

Comment: I just noticed the auto-complete mode is not enabled...the package is installed successfully.

Comment: @city Glad to know it's working for you now.

Answer (score 3):

You must add the urls for gnu, melpa, marmalade repositories in .emacs file

```
(setq package-archives 
  '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")))
```

After doing this, run `M-x package-refresh-contents` and `M-x auto-complete`. It should work.

Comment: `package-refresh-contents` is like `yum update` and if i am not wrong, it caches the list of available packages on remote url.

Comment: I followed your instruction. it still prompted no match :(

Comment: and I run M-x list-packages, no auto-complete  was in the list

Comment: did you do `M-x eval-buffer` to ensure that the emacs load the new emacs file?

Comment: @city after adding those lines to your init file, you need to restart Emacs.

Comment: @Malabarba, I did restart emacs. But it doesn't work.