# compiling warning when installing auto-complete package in emacs 24

Tags: auto-complete-mode

I tried to install auto-complete and followed the steps below:

(emacs version: GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.18.9))

1) delete dir elpa (make sure it's not installed)

2) M-x package-install RET auto-complete RET

```
 Leaving directory `/home/taochen/.emacs.d/elpa/popup-20150315.612'
 ^L
 Compiling file /home/taochen/.emacs.d/elpa/popup-20150315.612/popup-pkg.el at Tue Apr 14 10:47:58 2015
 Entering directory `/home/taochen/.emacs.d/elpa/popup-20150315.612/'
 ^L
 Compiling file /home/taochen/.emacs.d/elpa/popup-20150315.612/popup.el at Tue Apr 14 10:47:58 2015
 ^L
 Compiling no file at Tue Apr 14 10:47:58 2015
 Leaving directory `/home/taochen/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete-20150408.1132'
^L
Compiling file /home/taochen/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete-20150408.1132/auto-complete-config.el at Tue Apr 14 10:47:58 2015
Entering directory `/home/taochen/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete-20150408.1132/'

In end of data:
auto-complete-config.el:544:1:Warning: the following functions are not known to be defined:
    semantic-analyze-current-context, semantic-tag-class,
    semantic-tag-function-arguments, yas-expand-snippet,
    semantic-format-tag-type, semantic-format-tag-name
^L
Compiling file /home/taochen/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete-20150408.1132/auto-complete.el at Tue Apr 14 10:47:59 2015
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking about. Warnings usually concern the developer of the package.

Comment: Is the package installed? These warnings do not mean the package failed to install, you can typically ignore them unless it actually failed to compile.

Comment: I just noticed the auto-complete mode is not enabled....the package is installed

Comment: It is the norm for installed packages not to automatically enable themselves and to require extra configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. I would venture to say that the majority of packages on ELPA trigger some warning(s).

*If you build Emacs from source, you'll notice that even Emacs' own files trigger warnings too*.

Warnings are not fatal. And it's often a bit of a pain to fix them, so developers may not spend the time to fix them.

Sometimes, warnings are unavoidable. As a developer myself, I usually wrap the offending code in `(with-no-warnings ...)`, but that's a matter of taste.

---

## TL;DR

Don't worry about them. They won't hurt you. :-)